# has_attribute? problem

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML document and I need to examine, whether some attribute is presented in element in question

**Suppose**, that the attribute is not presented.

When i say:

```
elem.has_attribute? "data-attr"
```

it returns nil instead of "false".

When i say:

```
elem["data-attr"].nil?
```

it returns "true", that is what i need.

But, when i say:

```
!elem["data-attr"].nil?
```

it retuns nil again.

When i say:

```
r = elem["data-attr"].nil?
r = !r
```

r gets "true" after the first line is executed

but, after the second line, "r" gets nil again

What the magic behind it ?

Comment: Funny - it seems to be documented as "returns true if attribute is present", but says nothing about attribute's absence.  Talk about complete documentation :(

Comment: xtofl, What the doc are you reading ? I'm looking at this "http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-get_attribute", but there is no explanation for this method.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html.  But based on the underlying Hash documentation, they can't do any better :)

Comment: @xtofl If you ask Nokogiri to find a node, you won't be using ActiveRecord's documentation. You have to use Nokogiri's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use:

```
elem["data-attr"].present?
```

or

```
elem["data-attr"].blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
elem["data-attr"].nil?
```

returns true, why wouldn't you expect

```
!elem["data-attr"].nil?
```

to return nil?

Comment: Because if elem["data-attr"].nil? is true, !true is false?

Comment: Yeah, but they both have falsiness.

Comment: They both have falseness, but its inconsistent: `!nil.nil? #=> false`